# Asynchronous task queues and asynchronous IO

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, celery

As I understand, asynchronous networking frameworks/libraries like twisted, tornado, and asyncio provide asynchronous IO through implementing nonblocking sockets and an event loop. Gevent achieves essentially the same thing through monkey patching the standard library, so explicit asynchronous programming via callbacks and coroutines is not required.

On the other hand, asynchronous task queues, like Celery, manage background tasks and distribute those tasks across multiple threads or machines. I do not fully understand this process but it involves message brokers, messages, and workers.

My questions,

1. Do asynchronous task queues require asynchronous IO? Are they in any way related? The two concepts seem similar, but the implementations at the application level are different. I would think that the only thing they have in common is the word "asynchronous", so perhaps that is throwing me off.
2. Can someone elaborate on how task queues work and the relationship between the message broker (why are they required?), the workers, and the messages (what are messages? bytes?).

Oh, and I'm not trying to solve any specific problems, I'm just trying to understand the ideas behind asynchronous task queues and asynchronous IO.

Comment: I've never heard the term `asynchronous task queue`. The obvious question would be: what is a synchronous task queue then? I think that the word is havily misused here.

Answer (score 3):

Asynchronous IO is a way to use sockets (or more generally file descriptors) without blocking. This term is specific to one process or even one thread. You can even imagine mixing threads with asynchronous calls. It would be completely fine, yet somewhat complicated.

Now I have no idea what `asynchronous task queue` means. IMHO there's only a task queue, it's a data structure. You can access it in asynchronous or synchronous way. And by "access" I mean `push` and `pop` calls. These can use network internally.

So task queue is a data structure. (A)synchronous IO is a way to access it. That's everything there is to it.

The term `asynchronous` is havily overused nowadays. The hype is real.

---

As for your second question:

1. Message is just a set of data, a sequence of bytes. It can be anything. Usually these are some structured strings, like JSON.
2. Task == message. The different word is used to notify the purpose of that data: to perform some task. For example you would send a message `{"task": "process_image"}` and your consumer will fire an appropriate function.
3. Task queue Q is a just a queue (the data structure).
4. Producer P is a process/thread/class/function/thing that pushes messages to Q.
5. Consumer (or worker) C is a process/thread/class/function/thing that pops messages from Q and does some processing on it.
6. Message broker B is a process that redistributes messages. In this case a producer P sends a message to B (rather then directly to a queue) and then B can (for example) duplicate this message and send to 2 different queues Q1 and Q2 so that 2 different workers C1 and C2 will get that message. Message brokers can also act as protocol translators, can transform messages, aggregate them and do many many things. Generally it's just a blackbox between producers and consumers.

As you can see there are no formal definitions of those things and you have to use a bit of intuition to fully understand them.

Answer (score 2):

Asynchronous tasks or celery tasks are just tasks that are executed asynchronously. In particular case of celery, tasks are executed by multiple workers thereby leveraging full benefits of threading, multiprocessing as well as distributed nodes. So in a way, we can easily accomplish what celery does by using libraries like `multiprocessing` or `multithreading`, but the benefit of using celery is it handles all that complexity by itself.

Now [Asyncronous IO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) is quite different from `multithreading` or `multiprocessing` does. Aync IO is suitable for tasks that are IO bound (not CPU). It executes multiple IO request simultaneously using single thread only. `Gevent` or `asyncio` (in case of python 3) helps in accomplishing that.

1. Celery - ideal for tasks that don't need to be realtime
2. Multiprocessing - ideal for tasks that are CPU bound.
3. Asyncio/Gevent - ideal for tasks that are IO bound
4. Multithreading - Due to inherent Global Interpreter Locking in Python, not of much use in CPU bound programs. In case of IO bound programs, I believe `asyncio` is a better option
5. Tornado - A framework that performs IO request asynchronously.
6. Twisted - A networking framework that provides lots of features besides Asynchronous IO.

Comment: I disagree with #4.  Python threads are real threads, and when used correctly can increase performance of IO bound programs.  They are not good for CPU bound work because the GIL is still a factor.

Comment: In IO bound programs, ayncio is a better option

Comment: That *may* be true, but asyncio isn't available in Python2.

Comment: I agree but there are other options like trollius, twisted etc.

Comment: Trollius is no longer maintained, and while I love Twisted (have used it for 8+ years) it is a completely different beast with a significant learning curve.  If someone wants to improve performance of an IO bound program (where multiple IO operations could run concurrently) then threading is just fine and is part of the standard lib.

Comment: And except maintaining legacy code, any big reason for not using Python 3? It's been a decade since the version is out

Comment: Besides I never said my answer is for Python 2x

Comment: upvoted! which one of these options do you think makes a lot of sense if you are a websocket client in python that wishes to receive WSS:// streams from several external APIs